# Accessing servers in China via encrypted channels (like SSH, HTTPS, VPN) from outside

Tags: ssh, vpn, https, china

I've been approached by a potential customer to manage certain servers in Mainland China, for which I would need to have access to them via encrypted channels (like SSH/HTTPS/VPN).

While I am aware of workarounds like reverse SSH, I was wondering if anyone can share some information about "fully compliant" ways which I could pursue? The customer has a legal entity in China, while I don't have one (and don't intend to).